# How to remove a substring from a string according to data inside

Tags: python, string

I have this string:

```
 row =   <line><a>111</a><b>222</b><c>333</c></line><line><a>444</a><b></b><c>555</c></line>
```

If `<b>` has no value I need all the line to be deleted from my string in this case:

```
  <line><a>444</a><b></b><c>555</c></line>
```

Should I split my row to an array and check each line than concat it to a new string without the lines that hold an empty b ?
Is there an easy/ smart way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.sub` we can try:

```py
row = '<line><a>111</a><b>222</b><c>333</c></line><line><a>444</a><b></b><c>555</c></line>'
output = re.sub(r'<line>(?:(?!<line>).)*<b></b>.*?</line>', '', row)
print(output)  # <line><a>111</a><b>222</b><c>333</c></line>
```

The `(?:(?!<line>).)` term in the regex used above will match content *without* crossing over the ending tag `</line>`, and is often referred to as "tempered dot."  The idea is that we want to match an empty `<b>` tag within `<line>`.

Note that for a more general solution consider using an XML parser.  Regex happens to work here assuming that all tags below `<line>` are single level and not nested deeply.

Comment: There's a possibly amusing post about how regex is not a robust solution to parsing HTML/XML: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1084416

Comment: @PeterWood A text explanation along with your URL drop would be helpful.

Comment: Fixed, and apologies for the initial dump